# Can the Opportunity Close Date be set to not be required?

Tags: opportunity

There are six stages in our sales process (not including Lost).  The request is can we customize so that opportunities in the first stage are not required to have a Close Date.  The request is for field entry requirement for Close Date not be triggered until progressing to the second stage.

I am checking to see if this is possible.

Comment: as noted in the answer, this can't be done - but you could default the closeDate for the initial stage to something far in the future so the Oppo doesn't appear in any forecast-type reports for the current fiscal quarter or year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- It is a required field.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm

[image]

Comment: And, why, exactly, is because it is used by the Forecasting feature, so without a date, it wouldn't know which quarter to forecast in to.